# How to show the same flutter app with different API urls depending on the user who enters?

Tags: android, flutter, api, dart

I have an application that is used by different users and diferents API urls, I need to have only  one app for the different users to enter and send the url of the API that corresponds to each user, but how can I do that validation?

Comment: For a better approach. You can have the feature of scanning the QR code first in the app if the app is used by different customers with different API URLs.
QR code data will be the API URL of that customer.

Comment: You should have a common entry point API for determining which user is active. That entry point API can supply further API URL information needed for that user once that user has been validated. Then store that API URL info on the device using a business strategy that makes sense for you. It's hard to be specific with an answer when your question is so vague.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can assign roles to each user, then have a class that encompasses the different urls available to each role the user belongs too, then at the entry of the app (authentication) check the user role and use your state management to enable the api that should be available to the user based on their roles.

Your question is not specific enough but I do hope this helps